# Flight Home from Schengen Area is past 90 days, but I will be travelling to other countries. Will this be a problem?

Tags: air-travel, schengen

I am spending 88 days in Italy, and then travelling for 2 weeks through the UK. It is surprisingly a lot cheaper to book a roundtrip ticket to Milan plus flights to and from Dublin than it is to book a flight to Milan and home from Dublin.

I will not be in the Schengen Area for longer than 88 days, but my flights will look like I am in Milan past the 90 day allowance.

Will this cause problems entering the country, or coming back to the US? Should I just cut my losses and spend the extra money on a multi-city flight?

Thanks!

Comment: "my flights will look like I am in Milan past the 90 day allowance." - why? You are leaving Schengen for the CTA and it's clearly visible in your passport.

Answer (score 4):

I fail to see where would a problem arise.

1. When you enter the area first, you can show your intent of leaving 88 days later. Not that they will grill a US citizen much.
2. When you leave the area, you have been there for 88 days.
3. When you seek to re-enter the area... but you don't. You are transiting airside. And even if you wouldn't, you have a stamp in your passport showing entering the Republic Of Ireland which also shows leaving the Schengen area.